# How to draw a line line using "*"

Tags: java

I am trying to draw a line using "`*`" in the console, but I get only 2 "`*`". I think something is wrong with the line algorithm. Maybe there is an easier way to do it.

Class MyGraphics:

```
 class MyGraphics {
int x, y;
private int width, height;
MyGraphics(int wid, int hit) {

    fb= new FrameBuffer(wid,hit);
    width = fb.getWidth();
    height = fb.getHeight();
}
MyGraphics() {
    fb = new FrameBuffer();
    width = fb.getWidth();
    height = fb.getHeight();
}

void drawLine(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2)
{
 width= x2 - x ;
height = y2 - y ;
   int dx1 = 0, dy1 = 0, dx2 = 0, dy2 = 0 ;
    if (width<0) dx1 = -1 ; else if (width>0) dx1 = 1 ;
   if (height<0) dy1 = -1 ; else if (height>0) dy1 = 1 ;
   if (width<0) dx2 = -1 ; else if (width>0) dx2 = 1 ;
   int longest = Math.abs(width) ;
   int shortest = Math.abs(height) ;
  if (!(longest>shortest)) {
    longest = Math.abs(height) ;
    shortest = Math.abs(width) ;
    if (height<0) dy2 = -1 ; else if (height>0) dy2 = 1 ;
    dx2 = 0 ;
}
int numerator = longest >> 1 ;
for (int i=0;i<=longest;i++) {
    fb.setPixel(x1, y1);

    numerator += shortest ;
    if (!(numerator<longest)) {
        numerator -= longest ;
        x += dx1 ;
        y += dy1 ;
    } else {
        x += dx2 ;
        y += dy2 ;
    }
}
return;
}
void display() {
    fb.display();
    return;
    } // simply calls the frame buffer's display method

FrameBuffer fb;
}



/*void drawLine(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2)
{
width= x2 - x ;
height = y2 - y ;
int dx1 = 0, dy1 = 0, dx2 = 0, dy2 = 0 ;
if (width<0) dx1 = -1 ; else if (width>0) dx1 = 1 ;
if (height<0) dy1 = -1 ; else if (height>0) dy1 = 1 ;
if (width<0) dx2 = -1 ; else if (width>0) dx2 = 1 ;
int longest = Math.abs(width) ;
int shortest = Math.abs(height) ;
if (!(longest>shortest)) {
    longest = Math.abs(height) ;
    shortest = Math.abs(width) ;
    if (height<0) dy2 = -1 ; else if (height>0) dy2 = 1 ;
    dx2 = 0 ;
}
int numerator = longest >> 1 ;
for (int i=0;i<=longest;i++) {
    fb.setPixel(y, x);

    numerator += shortest ;
    if (!(numerator<longest)) {
        numerator -= longest ;
        x += dx1 ;
        y += dy1 ;
    } else {
        x += dx2 ;
        y += dy2 ;
    }
}
return;
}*/
```

Class MyGraphicsApp:

```
class MyGraphicsApp {
MyGraphicsApp() {mg = new MyGraphics(80, 25);}

void paint(MyGraphics g) {
    g.drawLine(5, 12, 27, 2);
    g.drawLine(2, 2, 30, 30);
}

void repaint() {
    paint(mg);
    mg.display();
}

public static void main(String [] args) {
    MyGraphicsApp myGraphicsApp = new MyGraphicsApp();
    myGraphicsApp.repaint();
}

MyGraphics mg;
}
```

Comment: What is "drewan line"? Do you mean "draw a line"?

Comment: That dictionary says no result for "drewan".

Comment: Well, for one, x1 and y1 are never even changed, so fb.setPixel(x1,y1) will hardly do much except output a single pixel continuously ... scrap the whole drawLine function and start again from basics doing just one diagonal instead of all 4+ directions, then build on that. That should make it easier for you, you're overcomplicating things for yourself right now, you don't understand this code at all. Rewrite the function again, trust me. Start with an extremely basic one...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this assignments

```
width= x2 - x ;
height = y2 - y ;
```

should be

```
width= x2 - x1 ;
height = y2 - y1 ;
```

And this line is wrong also

```
fb.setPixel(x1, y1);
```

since you never change the values of `x1` and `y1`.